# Backbone view instantiation issue

Tags: backbone.js

Unexpectedly, the following code will print `Test1 undefined` instead of `Test1 Test2`.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        console.log(this.collection, this.test);
    }
});

new MyView({collection: "Test1", test: "Test2"});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the following properties from the **options** argument get merged in as view properties.

> model, collection, el, id, attributes, className, tagName  ([See the source code](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L881))

Any other property gets placed on the **options** property of the view.

So to access the **test** property from the initialize method, you can update your code as follows.

```
console.log(this.collection, this.options.test);
```

Comment: Ugh, Why!? This seems so unnecessary and unnatural.

Comment: @Randomblue: Ever heard of encapsulation? And this behavior is part of the [documented interface](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#View-constructor) so it shouldn't be surprising.

Comment: @muistooshort: Not really. Could you point to a good article explaining encapsulation please?

Comment: @Randomblue: Encapsulation is a pretty basic programming concept, maybe start at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(object-oriented_programming)). If Backbone copied the whole options objects into `this` then you'd be overwriting internal methods and properties and that would lead to all sorts of strange and interesting bugs.